# Searching html elements based on data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to search elements based on data attributes?

I have the following code and would like to know how can this be achieved

```
<UL>
    <LI data-relation_id=1/>
    <LI data-relation_id=1/>
    <LI data-relation_id=1/>
    <LI data-relation_id=2/>
    <LI data-relation_id=2/>
    <LI data-relation_id=2/>
    <LI data-relation_id=3/>
    <LI data-relation_id=3/>
    <LI data-relation_id=3/>
</UL>
```

On a click event I basically want to find out all the items that belong to a specific data-relation?

```
function getRelatedObjects(relationId){
   //Search all the li's and get the LI 
   //that have the data-relation_id== relationId

}
```

Can this be done using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data attribute is just an attribute, so you can use the attribute selector.

```
$('li[data-relation_id='+relationId+']')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't search by associated data specifically, but if the data is set by attribute then you can search using the attribute selector:

```
function getRelatedObjects(relationId){
   return $('li[data-relation_id="'+relationId+'"]');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/6fHuN/)